# Is there relation between K-Framework and structural operational semantics?

Tags: programming-languages, semantics, operational-semantics, denotational-semantics

[K-framework](http://www.kframework.org/index.php/Main_Page) strives to give one (instead of two - operational and denotational) semantics for industrial programming languages. The same unification is done by structural operational semantic as well. Are those two frameworks related somehow? Such relation could be very frutiful, because K-framework has excellent tools and full completed semantics, but SOS has deep theory and connection with category theory.

Comment: SOS has connections with category theory? I did not know this. I always thought only denotational semantics was category-theoretic, while SOS was category-free. Maybe I'll open a question on it

Comment: Of course, there is http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397504004463

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1567832610000160 has review about SOS connection with K, studying it..